# Scanf warning %[^\n]

Tags: c, warnings

How I can remove this warning:

```
>  warning: format ‘%[^ ’ expects type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type
> ‘char (*)[1024]’
```

code looks like this:

```
char a[1024];
scanf("%[^\n]", &a);
```

Comment: Try scanf("%[^\n]", a);

Comment: Step 1: Don't use `scanf`, use `sscanf`. Step 2: Pass in `a` directly, not `&a`.

Comment: not work, no read text from stdin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use code as

```
char a[1024];
scanf("%[^\n]", a);
```

(note: removal of '&' )